# Set-theoretic worries about functor transformation from $\text{Id}$ to $V\mapsto V^*$

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

Upon reading the wikipedia article for natural transformations of functors, I stumbled across the section on the [dual of a vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation#Example:_dual_of_a_finite-dimensional_vector_space). This is not a question about why the transformation from the identity functor to the dual functor is not natural, rather a worry about how this transformation is defined, set-theoretically speaking.

Denote by $\mathbf{Vec}$ the category of all finite-dimensional vector spaces over some fixed field $k$ with linear maps as morphisms.
Then we have a functor $*\colon \mathbf{Vec}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathbf{Vec}$ sending a space $V$ to its dual space $V^*$, and a linear map $L$ to its dual map $L^*$.
A transformation from $\text{Id}_{\mathbf{Vec}}$ to $*$ requires to choose an isomorphism from $V$ to $V^*$ for *every* vector space $V$.
(This comes down to choosing a nondegenerate bilinear form $V\times V \to k$ for every $V$.)

My worry is that this definition requires 'too many' choices.
For any *set* of vector spaces $\{V_\alpha\}_\alpha$, the axiom of choice would imply that we can make a choice of isomorphism $V_\alpha \to V_\alpha^*$ for all $\alpha$ simultaneously. But of course, the collection of all vector spaces does not form a set, but rather a proper class.
As stated, I'm not convinced we can properly define this transformation.

Is there any non-problematic way of defining or talking about such a transformation, then?

Comment: What is "this transformation" ? Note that a priori (unless you specify some definitions) such a natural transformation wouldn't even make sense because the two functors don't have the same codomain

Comment: @Max The functors $\text{Id}_{\mathbf{Vec}}$ and $*$ have the same domain and codomain as I defined them (namely $\mathbf{Vec}$). What more data would be required to even talk about a transformation between them, then?

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht "Taking the dual" is a contravariant functor, so its domain should really be $\mathbf{Vec}^{op}$ instead of $\mathbf{Vec}$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks, edited.

Comment: Global choice is consistent, and in fact often assumed when one works with classes. Exactly because this sort of problems shouldn't *really* matter, unless one investigates the necessity of global choice principles for these kind of questions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks! I hadn't heard of global choice before, so that answers my question :)

Comment: Many functors arise from some universal property, and to really define them one needs to choose representative from isomorphism classes. Luckily, in this case, whatever choice we make, it's unique up to unique natural transformation.